# Seridei Ha'Eish by Yechiel Yaakov Weinberg

Tags: books-generally, internet, product-recommendation

Does anyone know where I can find the sefer Seridei Ha'Eish online?  I want to find it for free, but at the very least, does anyone know of the cheapest price for me to buy it?

Answer (score 5):

You can view it in the online version of Otzar Hachochma, though only the first 40 pages of each volume is accessible for free.
Links: [1](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?13807&BOOKS), [2](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?102673&BOOKS), [3](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?13012&BOOKS), [4](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?13013&BOOKS).

[Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99+%D7%90%D7%A9&btnG=Search+Books) also has a "snippet view" for some volumes, which may be useful for searching.

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought a copy for 50 shekels (14$ !) at sefer.org.il ([here](https://www.sefer.org.il/items/4869511-%D7%A9%D7%95-%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%A9-%D7%91-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D)) for the two-volume edition. An amazing bargain for an amazing sefer.